# IIS 7 Forms Authentication

Tags: iis-7, forms-authentication

In IIS 7 is there a way to edit the forms authentication portion of the web.config without editing the web.config directly? That is, using the IIS 7 GUI to make changes to the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify the web.config directly for this case.